# Action Script 3 Timer Not Stopping

Tags: actionscript-3, timer

Okay, so I am a very amateur AS3 programmer. I have a timer setup, and after 45 seconds it should move to scene 6, however if it calls hitTestObject, it should stop and reload from 0 when the scene reloads. EDIT: I know this code is probably really bad coding, I'm also taking tips on how to fix this code up. Here's my code:

```
 var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 1); // 1 second
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onEnterFrame);
myTimer.start();
```

{MAIN FUNCTION}

```
function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void {

var startTime:int=getTimer();


var currentTime:int=getTimer();
trace(currentTime);

if (currentTime>45000){
gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 6");

}
}
```

My issue, is that the timer keeps running when it hits test object and so when scene 3 is reloaded, the timer just keeps going. Therefore you only have to play for a total of 45 seconds, no matter how many times you die. It should be that once you die the timer reloads when you reload scene 3. Any ideas on what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
var myTimer:Timer;

function resetTimer():void
{
    // check if timer already initialize
    if(myTimer != null)
    {
        // just reset
        myTimer.stop();
        myTimer.reset();
    }
    else
    {
        // initialize timer and set a 45 sec delay;
        myTimer = new Timer(45*1000,1);
        myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, handleTimerTick);
    }    

    myTimer.start();

}

function handleTimerTick(event:TimerEvent):void
{ 
    // stop and null timer;
    myTimer.stop();
    myTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, handleTimerTick);
    myTimer = null;

    // goto my 6th scene 
    gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 6");
}

// whenever a hit test is performed and a timer reset is needed just call
resetTimer();
```

Comment: how could one removeEventListener from various timers, without knowing the callBack method for each listener?

Comment: @zonabi could you please elaborate your question? I am afraid I do not understand it.  Just in case you mean "why I remove the event listener in the timer handler" , please consider that 1. timer is stopped after first trigger  2. timer will trigger the handler method in any case just once ( see timer constructor ) 3. which "callBack" function are you pointing ?

Comment: well, it ended up not being an issue because the function the various timers called did end up being the same. but we were wondering, if there were timers calling different methods, if there was a way to remove all event listeners regardless of whatever method they are calling, (since the removeEventListener requires you put in that method as a param). if it still doesn't make sense, forgetaboutit! thanks

Comment: @zonabi It is not possible to do what you are asking, also I am not sure but I think it is a bad practice to do that. You could still make use of the ".hasEventListener(...)" method and check if specific listeners are in place.